# Pyomo cannot iterate over abstract Set and constraint index error

Tags: pyomo

I am new to Pyomo so this may be a silly question to ask. I am trying to build a 4-zone UC/ED model with many generators in each zone. So I set the model up in the following way:

```
model.Zone1Generators = Set()

model.Zone2Generators = Set()

model.Zone3Generators = Set()

model.Zone4Generators = Set()


model.Generators = model.Zone1Generators | model.Zone2Generators | model.Zone3Generators | model.Zone4Generators
```

When I run the model, I got the following error message:

> ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint Local1:
>       RuntimeError: Cannot iterate over abstract Set 'Zone1Generators' before it has been constructed (initialized).

The related constraint is posted below:

```
def WECC1(i): 
if i > 0:
    seg1 = sum(model.mwh_1[j,i] for j in model.Zone1Generators) 
    seg2 = sum(model.mwh_2[j,i] for j in model.Zone1Generators) 
    seg3 = sum(model.mwh_3[j,i] for j in model.Zone1Generators) 
    renew = model.hydro[model.zones[0],i] + model.solar[model.zones[0],i]\
    + model.wind[model.zones[0],i] + model.pumpstorage[model.zones[0],i]
    return seg1 + seg2 + seg3 + renew >=  0.25*model.HorizonDemand[model.zones[0],i]
else:
    return Constraint.Skip
model.Local1= Constraint(rule=WECC1)
```

I think it may be caused by the fact that I didn’t pass all the model information. So I changed the constraint from `def WECC1(i)` to `WECC1(model,i)`. This gives me a new error message:

> ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:
>       WECC1() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the indexing set to the constraint in order to declare an indexed constraint

```
model.Local1 = Constraint(model.Generators, rule=WECC1)
```